# Where to put code from a preliminary gem in a rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm working on a government transparency app.  For the app I'm using two different APIs from the sunlight foundation.  One already had a good gem wrapper that provided all the functionality I needed.  The other didn't, so I wrote the code myself with the plan of packaging it as a gem and using it in my app.  The code is done, but needs some refactoring as well some setup to properly turn it into a gem.  Unfortunately, I need to finish the app quickly for a demo I'm doing in a couple of days and just want to add the code to my existing app for the moment and then extract it out later to make a gem.

I'm a new programmer(about 3 months), so I'm still getting some of the convention and what not.  What I'm not sure is where to put the code in my rails app.  Does it go in the model, controller, or do I build a separate helper module.  The code for the app is here: https://github.com/gbcosgrove/sunlight-influence.  It consists of an API call constructor and then separate files for each category.  I'm still in the process of refactoring because I find it easier to just write code that works and then go back and iterate until its clean.

Any insight on where to put this code in an existing rails app not as a gem would be awesome.  Thank you so much!!

Comment: I'd use the `lib` folder, which is meant for code shared with other apps.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks.  I had never thought of that.

Comment: any folder under /app get's autoloaded, so you can put it wherever you like as long as you think it makes sense